# How do I move the image to the right side of the text? Help me please

Tags: html, css, web

So I have this code for my assignment but I can't figure out how to make the image goes to the side of the text. It keeps going to the right corner. Can someone help me out please? I just started to learn CSS. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="txt">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
    <button class="but1">Example</button>
    <button class="but2">Example</button><br>
    <img src="cy.png" alt="IMG">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a table

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="txt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
    <button class="but1">Example</button>
    <button class="but2">Example</button><br>
</td>
<td>
    <img src="cy.png" alt="IMG">
</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see you are started journey of css.

There is X ways to solve your problem with the help of css.

1. Float
2. Flexbox
3. Grid
4. Position

So for a beginner I would like to solve your problem with the help of float.
if you can not understand my code then you can take reference of any website to learn about css float property.

-------------CSS FILE-------------

```
    .content {
      float: right;
    }

    .image {
      float: left;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
```

------------- HTML File -------------

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
    <button class="but1">Example</button>
    <button class="but2">Example</button><br>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img
      src="your_image_path"
      alt="IMG">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to make this by CSS
you can use Float , FlexBox , Grid, Position

You can keep your HTML as it's but with a simple modification to put your img tag under the text

```
<div class="txt">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
    <img src="cy.png" alt="IMG">
    <button class="but1">Example</button>
    <button class="but2">Example</button><br>
```

In you CSS file you can use

```
    .txt {
    float: left;
    }
    
    .img {
    float: right;
    }

    button {
    clear: both;
    }
```

Hope this fix your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Could you clarify, are you trying to get it to go to the right side of text?

Typically, the `align` property of the `img` tag is what you want, and you usually want it before the thing you are trying to align it with.

I also recommend sharing a jsFiddle so that people can play with the code.

```
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13728847/pexels-photo-13728847.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="IMG" align="right">
<div class="txt">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
<button class="but1">Example</button>
<button class="but2">Example</button><be>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f1e7b6d8/